# Paypal Restful - Could not resolve host

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

i have a problem with the "Paypal PHP Restful SDK". My yproblem is, that (in sandbox mode) i get **sometimes** the error "**Could not resolve host** ...". This happens about every 10'th payment session in sandbox-mode.

Here the logged error:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PayPal\\Exception\\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Could not resolve host: api.sandbox.paypal.com' in /var/www/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:137
```

the corrospending line from the SDK is:

```
//Throw Exception if Retries and Certificates doenst work
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $ex = new PayPalConnectionException(
        $this->httpConfig->getUrl(),
        curl_error($ch),
        curl_errno($ch)
    );
    curl_close($ch);
    throw $ex;
}
```

Info: I have no Certificate on my vServer

Does somebody know, what is working wrong?

Comment: Paypal sdk , in sandbox mode, should return errors here and then to let you test and correctly treat these cases

Comment: @atrebbi Mind backing this statement with link to any official Paypal SDK documentation that describes this behaviour as intentional? I'd be surprised if you will.

Comment: the error condition should be set up in the sandbox account , to simulate errors ( negative testing , should be ; i don't remember if it can be setup up to fail always or even get random errors )

Answer (score 9):

There's insufficient information to fully diagnose the problem and find the the culprit. You can have i.e. networking problem on your run environment, DNS setup problem, connection timeouts etc etc. Yet as the issue occurs frequent enough to reproduce it you may try to resolve `api.sandbox.paypal.com` using other tools like `host` or `dig`, or you can even craft PHP script that would simply do:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
var_dump(gethostbyname('api.sandbox.paypal.com'));
```

and run it many times to see if the problem would occur here too. If it does, then I am afraid SO is not the right place to continue chasing this type of issues but as workaround/temporary fix you could either use IP (currently `173.0.82.78`) address instead of `api.sandbox.paypal.com` or edit your local `/etc/hosts` file and add

```
173.0.82.78  api.sandbox.paypal.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try flushing your DNS cache, restarting the network interface.
You can also try pinging and check if PayPal API is indeed pingable(reachable), try changing to Google DNS too, maybe that'll sort the issue.